# What is the mistake in this shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have written the following code..

```
installFunction(){

    perl Makefile.PL
    flag1 = $?

    make    
    flag2 = $?

    make install
    flag3 = $?

    make test
    flag4 = $?

    cd ..


    return $flag1 || $flag2 || $flag3 || $flag4
}
if(installFunction != 0)
    then
        echo "installation failure"
        exit
fi
```

But when I run the code , Im getting the following error

> ./install: 53: flag1: not found
>
> ./install: 53: flag2: not found
>
> ./install: 53: flag3: not found
>
> ./install: 53: flag4: not found

Could anyone say what the problem is?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can't read anything, reformat please.

Comment: `flag1=$?` no white-spaces around `=`

Comment: Spaces really matter in shell scripts.  Sometimes they must not be there, as in variable assignments; sometimes they must be there, as in after `if` statements.  That `if` will 'work', but not properly.
You should also consider (a) not doing `cd` in your main program by, for example, running a sub-shell and doing the `cd` in that, and (b) looking at `perl Makefile.PL && make && make test && make install` (test before installing!), and (c) remember that many modules use `Build.pl` instead of `Makefile.PL`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try

```
flag1=$?
```

notice the lack of spaces.

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/varassignment.html

---

And as kev mentioned, your `if` statement is invalid.

```
installFunction
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
        echo "installation failure"
        exit
fi
```

should work. obligatory link: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html

Answer (score 2):

The return statement is also wrong: `return $((flag1 | flag2 | flag3 | flag4))`

Answer (score 1):

The variable assignment is incorrect, `man bash` and read on **PARAMETERS**. That section should explain in details.

Your if statement syntax is incorrect, in the bash manual, read on **Compound Commands**

If I understand your if statement semantic, you want to check return code from your function call and verify if it is not zero? You should call your function and then get the return code using `$?`. Hence you need to do minor modification there though.

Last but not least, you can check your shell script for syntax errors by running command `sh -n script.sh`